# Running Spark application using HDFS or S3

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark, hdfs

In my spark application, I just want to access a big file, and distribute the computation across many nodes on EC2.

Initially, my file is stored on S3.

It's very convenient for me to load the file with `sc.textFile()` function from S3.

However, I can put some efforts to load the data to HDFS and then read the data from there.

My question is, will the performance be better with HDFS?

My code involves the spark `partitions(mapPartitions transforamtion)`, so does it really matter what is my initial file system?

Answer (score 2):

Obviously when using *S3* the latency is higher and the data throughput is lower compared to *HDFS* on local disk.

But it depends what you do with your data. It seems most of programs are limited more by CPU power than network throughput. So you should be fine with the *1Gbps* throughput that you get from S3.

Anyway you can check recent slides from *Aaron Davidson's* talk on Spark Summit 2015. This topic is discussed there.

http://www.slideshare.net/databricks/spark-summit-eu-2015-lessons-from-300-production-users/16

Comment: *"the 1Gbps throughput that you get from S3"*: S3 is not limited to 1Gbps. You will hit the EC2 instance bottleneck before S3. The largest EC2 instances come with a 10Gbps NIC. If you can't get more than 1Gbps, there's definitely something wrong: either the instance size is too small, or your application is simply not pushing hard enough. As I write this comment, I just tested a simple upload of a 50GB file from a single m4.10xl EC2 instance to S3 and got about 4Gbps with minimal effort (ie, simple aws s3 cp ...; I could probably spend more time optimizing to get higher throughput).